# Set HTTP/2 Pseudo-Header using node-libcurl?

Tags: node.js, http-headers, node-libcurl

I'm trying to send a request to a server using node-libcurl.  I have sample code using the built-in http2 library (my requirement is to use node-libcurl, this is not negotiable) which can receive a response from the server properly, but my node-libcurl code doesn't.  The main difference between the 2 is that the http2 code sets the pseudo-headers `:scheme`, `:path`, `:method`, and `:authority` while the node-libcurl code does not.  I tried setting them using the normal node-libcurl headers but that didn't work.

Is there any way to set these pseudo-headers using node-libcurl?  The docs are written in C and I'm not sure how or if they translate to Node.

Thanks!